# Problema com o código ( Buscar valores entre uma data e outra na base de dados )

Tags: php, mysql

O problema é o seguinte. Estou a trabalhar num código que vai buscar uma série de voos que estão disponíveis entre uma data e outra inseridas pelo utilizador. As datas são inseridas através do datepicker em js, mas penso que essa parte esteja a funcionar bem e não esteja relacionado com o problema. Contudo ainda não tive sucesso, os dados nunca são retornados. Já usei as condições if para alterar o retorno dos dados mas continua em erro. Penso que tenha a ver o parâmetro $_GET mal aplicado. Agradecia imenso todo o apoio prestado, em caso de ser necessário mais alguma informação, solicite que a coolocarei de imediato.

```
 <?php

if (isset($_GET["botao"])){
$parms = array();
$filter = array();

$query = "SELECT V.ID FROM voo as V WHERE ";
    if (isset($_GET["origem"]) && !empty($_GET["origem"])) {
        $filter[] = "(V.IDLocalOrigem=?)";
        $parms[] = $_GET["origem"];
    }

    $query = "SELECT V.ID FROM voo as V WHERE ";
    if (isset($_GET["destino"]) && !empty($_GET["destino"])) {
        $filter[] = "(V.IDLocalDestino=?)";
        $parms[] = $_GET["destino"];
    }

    $query = "SELECT V.ID FROM voo as V WHERE ";
    if (isset($_GET["data"]) && !empty($_GET["data"])) {
        $filter[] = "(V.DataPartida>=?)";
        $parms[] = $_GET["data"];
    }

    $query = "SELECT V.ID FROM voo as V WHERE ";
    if (isset($_GET["entre"]) && !empty($_GET["entre"])) {
        $filter[] = "(V.DataChegada<=?)";
        $parms[] = $_GET["entre"];
    }

}       


        $query .= explode(' AND ',$filter);

   ?>       

        <pre><?php var_dump($filter); ?></pre>
  <?php



    /*$query= "select V.ID, V.IDLocalOrigem, L1.Nome, V.IDLocalDestino,".
    " L2.Nome, V.IDAviao, V.DataPartida, V.DataChegada,".
    " V.PrecoBilhete, V.Estado, L1.Nome as nomeOrigem, L2.Nome as nomeDestino".
    " FROM Voo as V".
    " INNER JOIN Local as L1 ON V.IDLocalOrigem = L1.ID".
    " INNER JOIN Local as L2 ON V.IDLocalDestino = L2.ID".
    " WHERE ((V.IDLocalOrigem=?) OR (? is NULL)) AND".
    " ((V.IDLocalDestino=?) OR (? is NULL)) AND".
    " ((V.DataPartida>=?) OR (? is NULL)) AND".
    " ((V.DataPartida<=?) OR (? is NULL)) AND".
    " ((V.PrecoBilhete=?) OR (? is NULL)) AND".
    " ((V.Estado=?) OR (? is NULL))";*/


      // RESOLVER: Pesquisar todos os voos entre datas
    $stmt = $mydb->prepare($query);
    $Origem = !empty($_GET["origem"]) ? $_GET["origem"] : null;
    $Destino =!empty($_GET["destino"]) ? $_GET["destino"] : null;
    $DataPartida = null;
    if (!empty($_GET["data"])){
        $DataPartida = $_GET["data"].' 00:00:00';   
    }
    if (!empty($_GET["entre"])){
        $DataChegada = $_GET["entre"].' 23:59:59';  
    }

    $Preco = null;

    $Estado = null;

    $stmt->bind_param("iiii", $Origem, $Destino, 
    $DataPartida $DataChegada);

    $stmt->execute();


    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $todosDados = $result->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC);

    foreach($todosDados as $r   )
        {
        echo "<h1>Ida</h1>";

        echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";

        echo "Origem:".$r["nomeOrigem"]."</br>";
        echo "Destino:".$r["nomeDestino"]."</br>";
        echo "DataPartida:".$r["DataPartida"]."</br>";
        echo "DataChegada:".$r["DataChegada"]."</br>";
        echo "Preço:".$r["PrecoBilhete"]."</br>";
        echo "Estado:".$r["Estado"]."</br>";
        echo '<a href="lugares.php?idvoo='.$r["ID"].'" class="btn btn-primary">Comprar</a>';

        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        }   

    $result->free();


    $stmt->bind_param("iiii", $Origem, $Destino, 
    $DataPartida, $DataChegada);

    $stmt->execute();


    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $todosDados = $result->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC);




    foreach($todosDados as $r   )
        {
        echo "<h1>Ida</h1>";

        echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";

        echo "Origem:".$r["nomeOrigem"]."</br>";
        echo "Destino:".$r["nomeDestino"]."</br>";
        echo "DataPartida:".$r["DataPartida"]."</br>";
        echo "DataChegada:".$r["DataChegada"]."</br>";
        echo "Preço:".$r["PrecoBilhete"]."</br>";
        echo "Estado:".$r["Estado"]."</br>";
        echo '<a href="lugares.php?idvoo='.$r["ID"].'" class="btn btn-primary">Comprar</a>';

        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        }   

    $result->free();
    $stmt->close();
?>
```

O $filter apresenta este var_dump:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "(V.IDLocalOrigem=?)"
  [1]=>
  string(20) "(V.IDLocalDestino=?)"
  [2]=>
  string(18) "(V.DataPartida>=?)"
  [3]=>
  string(18) "(V.DataChegada<=?)"
}
```

Comment: Qual o problema? Não está retornando dados da consulta?

Comment: @Lúcio Rubens Exactamente, nunca retorna dados.

Comment: Posta a sua variável `$query`

Comment: @Lúcio Rubens Como assim? fazer print_r ou echo do $query?

Comment: O código, pois deve ser problema com a consulta, e vc já inicia com: `$stmt = $mydb->prepare($query);`

Comment: @Lúcio Rubens Já postei o valor da query. Será que o problema vem daí? vou verificar.

Comment: @angelfmf o problema é desse query. e que tal criar o query de forma dinâmica consoante cada um dos parametros esteja preenchido ou não, em vez de usar isto: `((V.DataPartida>=?) OR (? is NULL))`? Já confirmou se isto funciona sequer?

Comment: @BlunT Como faço para criar o query desse modo, pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: @angelfmf era implode em vez de explode. enganei-me...

Comment: @angelfmf sugiro um print ao $query depois do implode. tens ai uma linha duplicada desnecessariamente `$query = "SELECT V.ID FROM voo as V WHERE ";`

Comment: Este é o print da query que sugeriu:      SELECT V.ID FROM voo as V WHERE (V.IDLocalOrigem=?) AND (V.IDLocalDestino=?) AND (V.DataPartida>=?) AND (V.DataChegada<=?)  Parece estar bem certo?

Comment: @angelfmf certissimo! o bind_param é que está mal porque nesse caso só ha 4 variaveis

Comment: @BlunT Continua a aparecer o erro " mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables, já tentei modicicar o bind_param de várias maneiras mas dá sempre o mesmo erro. Não entendo o que estou a fazer de mal

Comment: @angelfmf o que estás a fazer deve ser adicionar parametros a mais no bind_param do que aqueles que estão a ser definidos no query. tens de criar outro array para os parametros, da mesma forma que o $filter, e ir adicionando os valores a esse array, e depois chamares o bind_param com base nesse array. dessa forma terás sempre o numero de campos correcto.

Comment: @BlunT Tenho estado a fazer debugging e ver onde haveriam mais problemas e quando fiz em    `$todosDados = $result->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC) or trigger_error($result->error);` aparece este erro:  "Undefined property: mysqli_result::$error"

Answer (score 1):

Segue aqui um exemplo de como montar o query dinâmico:

```
$parms = array();
$filter = array();
$query = "(...) WHERE ";
if (isset($_GET["origem"]) && !empty($_GET["origem"])) {
    $filter[] = "(V.IDLocalOrigem=?)";
    $parms[] = $_GET["origem"];
}

[fazer o mesmo para os restantes parametros]

$query .= implode(' AND ', $filter);

[executar o query com os parametros que foram preenchidos]
```

Atenção que o código não foi testado, pode ter algum erro.

Comment: Não se preocupe, vou já trabalhar com o que fornceceu. Muito Obrigado*

Comment: Pronto, já escrevi o cóodigo (editado acima) mas não consigo passar da função explode, dá um Warning que diz que "$filter" tem de ser string.

Comment: @angelfmf é implode, enganei-me. vou corrigir

Comment: Obrigado, já corrigi, eu estive a pesquisar e acrescentei o implode apenas ao $filter mas agora o código já prossegue. No entanto ainda tem erros, não se executei bem a query dinamica. Fiz um var_dump com os valores do filter, pode ser que ajude a perceber se está a ir buscar os valores certos. Vou editar na pergunta

Comment: @angelfmf não esquecer que o bind_param já não leva todos os parametros, mas apenas aqueles que foram preenchidos no query.

Comment: Só uma dica: caso o array ``$filter`` não seja incrementado, sua SQL passaria a ser ``SELECT (campos) FROM tabela WHERE``, ou seja, erro de sintaxe. Inicialize sua variável ``$query`` com **$query = "(...) WHERE 1=1 ";** (caso **$filter** não seja incrementado, traz todos.

Comment: @mend3 sim, quando fiz o código foi de cabeça, nem pensei nisso. a alternativa é só colocar o where caso `count($filter) > 0`